# Azure AD, Angular Spa and Spring Microservice Integration

Tags: azure, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

We are using Azure AD for authentication and authorization. Our angular spa has been enabled SSO with Azure AD. We need to secure our backend
service and only allow API which has a valid jwt token.

What we have done so far is:

1. Registered our angular app in Azure AD.
2. We have configured spring microservice as a resource server and
   application properties contain jwt.issuer-uri

   **spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=XXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX**

The issue is the token that we get from Azure AD is having an audience as **"00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"** which means the token is generated for the **Microsoft graph**. I also tried accessing graph Api with this token and it worked. But what we want is to verify this token in our own spring microservice and grant permission
based on jwt provided.

To solve this issue I had to make some config changes in our Azure registered Angular app. I have added a custom **scope api://<>/app** and use
this scope while acquiring the token. Now the token is being validated in the backend and API working fine.

This config somehow works but doesn't seem correct to me. I am new to azure so am not sure how all things tie-up.

1. The new token which is now being generated has an audience as our
   angular spa client Id. Is this correct? Shouldn't it be the backend
   service? Any why it's getting validated by the backend with the
   current configuration?
2. My understanding is that we don't have to register our spring
   microservice with Azure Ad. I will just act as a resource server and
   will decode the token provided by the angular app using the
   issuer-url.
3. In case we need to register our backend services with azure AD then
   would it be difficult to do the same for all microservices?

I have done all settings by referencing.
https://ordina-jworks.github.io/security/2020/08/18/Securing-Applications-Azure-AD.html

In some other links, I find a completely different config for setting up backend service. I am not sure which one is correct.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/active-directory-spring-boot-starter-readme?view=azure-java-stable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure AD is a little confusing when following a standards based approach. I wrote a [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/12/01/azure-ad-spa-code-sample/) on this a couple of years back:

- You have already figured out that you need at least one API registration to work, to expose an API scope - so that you get usable access tokens
- The generated id from the API entry in Azure then becomes your audience, as in step 9 of the article.

What we'd really like to do is this, so that we can do things like forward the JWT in microservice to microservice calls:

- Get Azure AD to issue an audience claim such as api.mycompany.com that is common to all microservices
- Issue multiple scopes in the access tokens, based on areas of data in microservices - as in [this Curity doc](https://curity.io/resources/learn/scope-best-practices/)

I would aim for a single entry in Azure AD to represent your platform of APIs. Then each microservice can use the same generated audience value.

Hopefully you can get multiple custom scopes to work also, though there are some annoyances here, especially when you want to use built in OpenID Connect User Info scopes, which Azure AD exposes via the Graph API.

Comment: Thanks for reverting and sharing the useful information. Just one more follow-up question, as I said that as of now I have only
registered Angular SPA in Azure AD and have not registered any app for API. Instead what I did was, exposed a new Api scope
within the registered Angular SPA app. So now In my access token, I am getting the audience the same as my angular SPA client id in Azure.
But I am not sure why this token is getting successfully validated by the backend service. Maybe by default is don't verify the audience

Comment: From your post what I understand is that I need to create a new app registration for API and add it in API permission for SPA so that the access
token contains the audience as Azure backend API client id. And then enforce custom validation at each microservice to validate the audience.

Also like you said and even I was on the same page to use the same token across all microservices. But is that a correct approach from a security point? From
angular SPA user was granted a token to call API "X" on resource server "A" but he can use the same token to call API "Y" on resource server "B".

Comment: On the other hand, If I don't use the same token across microservices then it would be very tedious to always generate a new token in resource server A(spring microservice) to call a Rest endpoint on resource server B. Also in this case the angular app we will need to have some logic to dynamically get the token from azure AD for different Azure Ad registered Backend Api apps(Different app registration for each microservice in Azure AD) depending on which resource server API call was called by the user.

Comment: As a default mechanism, access tokens are designed to be sent between microservices. Eg user authenticates with scopes 'orfers + shipping', then the UI calls the orders service which in turn calls the shipping service. This provides a convenient coding model.

Comment: The exception is when the UI wants to do something high privilege such as payment. In this case it makes sense to redirect the user again to get a different type of token. In most cases a single token is used though.